# Microsoft Sharepoint Foundation - revision control for documents

Tags: sharepoint

For what kind of file types does MSF support revision control ? Can I put for example Rar, Zip or Images files under revision control in MSF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint will allow you to upload any type of file and have it controlled by document versioning. (Assuming it is under the upper size limit, and not in the blocked file types list.)

Whether you want to or not is another question. Depending on the size of the files/etc. it may be "cheaper" to find another solution.

See [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20120618011323/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/joelo/archive/2007/11/08/what-not-to-store-in-sharepoint.aspx) for some general storage recommendations. It was targeted at WSS (SharePoint 2007) but I think it still applies in 2010.